# jQuery: Side Dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, sidebar

I am working with a sidebar, and I wanted it so when I hover over the sidebar, two options slide out (with .slide). This is what I have so far:

```
       $("#userFActivator").hover(
            function () {
                $("#userF").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
            },
            function () {
                setTimeout(next(), 400);
                function next() {
                    if ($("#userF").is(":hover") === true) {
                        $("#userF").show();
                    } else {
                        $('#userF').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 400);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

All it gives me is a really glitchy sidebar, when I hover over the options they go away. Is there a solution that enables me to, when I hover over the options, have them stay so a user can click them before they go away? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to put you menu parent elements in a container and do the same with menu child items:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='label'>Menu item 1</span>
        <ul class='submenu'>
            <!-- etc. -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='label'>Menu item 2</span>
        <ul class='submenu'>
            <!-- etc. -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your javascript, put the ':hover' selector on `<li/>`'s, while `slide`-ing the child `<ul class='submenu'/>`-s.

Comment: Might I be able to do that with <div>s?

Comment: You can use pretty much any tags, as long as you maintain this structure and use correct jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code.

`setTimeout(next(), 400);` - In this code `next()` will get executed right away and not after 400 ms because you are calling the function instead of passing its reference.

Next is you can use an anonymous function instead of defining it every time.

Try this.

```
   $("#userFActivator").hover(
        function () {
            $("#userF").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
        },
        function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if ($("#userF").is(":hover") === true) {
                    $("#userF").show();
                } else {
                    $('#userF').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 400);
                }
            }, 400);
        }
    );
```